# VertexArrayObject, how can i set "default" attribute value?

Tags: opengl, attributes, shader, vao

I'm developing an OpenGL application and I'm trying to make ShaderPrograms and VAO's independent of each other. Saying independent I mean that both ShaderProgram and VAO can have different set of attributes.

While creating new ShaderProgram I explicitly bind list of known attributes to predefined locations even if shader does not use them.

```
  BindAttributeLocation(program, StandardAttribute.Position, PositionAttributeName);
  BindAttributeLocation(program, StandardAttribute.Color, ColorAttributeName);
  BindAttributeLocation(program, StandardAttribute.Normal, NormalAttributeName);
  BindAttributeLocation(program, StandardAttribute.TexCoord, TexCoordAttributeName);
  BindAttributeLocation(program, StandardAttribute.Tangent, TangentAttributeName);
```

Pretty same thing I'm trying to do with VAO, but if mesh does not contain data for attribute I want to set default value:

```
vao.Bind();
if(mesh.Color == null) {
    DisableVertexAttribArray(attribute);
    VertexAttrib4f(attribute, 1, 1, 1, 1);
}
else {
    EnableVertexAttribArray(attribute);
    buffer.Bind();
    BufferData(mesh.Color);
    VertexAttribPointer(attribute, ...);
}
```

This code seems to be working (so far), but I'm not sure if this is a correct approach. Where do VertexAttrib4f stores data: in VAO, or is it context global state and I need to reset it after each draw call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current attribute value is **not** part of the VAO state. The clearest statement in the spec that confirms this is in the description of `glGetVertexAttrib()` (emphasis added):

> Note that all the queries **except** CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB return values stored in the currently bound vertex array object

where `CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB` is the value you set with `glVertexAttrib4f()`.

This means that the values are global context state.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found good article about this: [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values)

> A vertex shader can read an attribute that is not currently enabled
>   (via glEnableVertexAttribArray​). The value that it gets is defined by
>   special context state, which is *not* part of the VAO.
>
> Because the attribute is defined by context state, it is constant over
>   the course of a single draw call. Each attribute index has a separate
>   value. Warning: Every time you issue a drawing command with an array
>   enabled, the corresponding context attribute values become undefined.
>   So if you want to, for example, use the non-array attribute index 3
>   after previously using an array in index 3, you need to repeatedly
>   reset it to a known value.
>
> The initial value for these is a floating-point (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)​.